# "E£" Symbol after amount in sales and POS

Tags: odoo, currency, odoo-9, point-of-sale

I am using **odoo 9**

In **sales & POS**, after the amount, **E£** symbol is shown like **0.00 E£** and cannot be removed.

*Changed the currency from EUR to SAR.*

All the modules shows amount correctly but in sales & POS it is like 0.00 E£

Answer (score 0):

It's Because in Sale Order Form while calling customer it take currency_id as price list's currency_id.

When you created the db, default currency may be EUR so its currency_id will be in EUR.

> Please enable "Advanced pricing based on formula" in sale settings and
>   Then you can find price list in Sale menu.
>
> Create Another Price list .

Then change the Price list in Sale order Form.

**Please check images .**

[This will be the current view with default price list in SO Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWxfB.jpg)

> I have created a pricelist called Test Price List and changed it with
>   Public.

[SO Form after Changing Price list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVBKs.jpg)